# Terraform dynamically loop over elements in a list and expand based on values

Tags: terraform

This is a bit hard to describe. So I have a map that looks like this after I've simplified it for clarity:

```
server_ip_configs = {
mgmt        = {
    ct      = "1"
    }
applicationgateway    = {
    ct      = "1"
    }
monitor     = {
    ct      = "1"
    }
app      = {
    ct      = "3"
    }
}
```

What I want to do is iterate over the map to create a flat list where elements are multiplied by the number of the ct property into a new flat list.
So we end up with a list that looks a bit like this:

```
server_ip_configs_mapped = [
       {
        name      = "mgmt-1"
        }
       {
        name      = "applicationgateway-1"
        }
       {
        name      = "monitor-1"
        }
       {
        name      = "app-1"
        }
       {
        name      = "app-2"
        }
       {
        name      = "app-3"
        }

    ]
```

Creating a list of elements for each row explicitly by setting a variable is trivial:

```
data "null_data_source" "server_list_ip_configs" {
  count = lookup(var.server_ip_configs[var.server_role], "ct", 0)

  inputs = {
    name    =   "${var.server_role}-${count.index +1}"
  }
}
```

I can put this in a module and call multiple instances of the module and concat the results. But this is not a nice way to do it and not at all DRY. Am I right in thinking there is no other way of doing this in Terraform? Is it because terraform is essentially declarative and maybe I should declare a list with multiple instance in it rather than try and generate one? 
Using a for loop won't work because you cant use an integer to iterate over explicitly from what I can see. So no:

```
for i in 5
```

Any answers to this welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

@Helder came close, but I interpreted the request slightly different. Your intentions are to build the list based on the ct value, which looks like a count. This should be what you are looking for. Notice the use of `range()` to do what you were looking in regard to the `for i in 5` statement.

```
variable "server_ip_configs" {
  default = {
    mgmt               = { ct = "1" }
    applicationgateway = { ct = "1" }
    monitor            = { ct = "1" }
    app                = { ct = "3" }
  }
}

locals {
  server_ip_configs_mapped = flatten([
    for server, count in var.server_ip_configs : [
      for i in range(count.ct) : {
        "name" = join("-", [server, i+1])
      }
    ]
  ])
}

output server_ip_configs_mapped { value = local.server_ip_configs_mapped }
```

Output:

```
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

server_ip_configs_mapped = [
  {
    "name" = "app-1"
  },
  {
    "name" = "app-2"
  },
  {
    "name" = "app-3"
  },
  {
    "name" = "applicationgateway-1"
  },
  {
    "name" = "mgmt-1"
  },
  {
    "name" = "monitor-1"
  },
]
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler! I'll test this but it looks exactly what i was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform 0.12 introduced for loops, you can do something like:

```
variable "server_ip_configs" {
  default = {
    mgmt               = { ct = "1" }
    applicationgateway = { ct = "1" }
    monitor            = { ct = "1" }
    app                = { ct = "3" }
  }
}

output "myout" {
  value = [for k, v in var.server_ip_configs : { "name" = join("-", [k, v.ct]) }]
}
```

---

Here the terraform output of that

```
terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

myout = [
  {
    "name" = "app-3"
  },
  {
    "name" = "applicationgateway-1"
  },
  {
    "name" = "mgmt-1"
  },
  {
    "name" = "monitor-1"
  },
]
```

Comment: Sorry Helder but that only takes me part way, I apologise for not explaining myself. I know I can loop over a list using for loops. But in your example you are not iterating over the inner loop implied by the ct. I need three items for app, app-1, app-2 and app-3 in that flat list. Your example only shows one (app-3).

Comment: @user1451104  Yep,  I missed that part ... but for future questions, if you know how to use loop always show an example of what you tried and what is not working in your code